# Linear Combination Function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given a Pandas Dataframe like this one:

```
from datetime import datetime
test = pd.DataFrame([
    {'id': 1, 'date': datetime.fromisoformat('2016-01-01'), 'a': 1}, 
    {'id': 1, 'date': datetime.fromisoformat('2016-01-02'), 'a': 2}, 
    {'id': 1, 'date': datetime.fromisoformat('2016-01-03'), 'a': 3}]
)
```

I am using a linear combination Python function:

```
def lin_comb(v1, v2, beta=0.9): 
    return beta*v1 + (1-beta)*v2
```

to generate  a column `lin_comb` based on column `a` with the followwing values:

```
    id  date        a   lin_comb
0   1   2016-01-01  1   1.000000
1   1   2016-01-02  2   1.099609
2   1   2016-01-03  3   1.290039
```

For example the value for the last row above is calculated via this expression:

```
(1 * 0.9 + 2 * 0.1) * 0.9 + 3 * 0.1 = 1.29
```

Here is the the whole executable code:

```
def lin_comb(v1, v2, beta=0.9): return beta*v1 + (1-beta)*v2

from datetime import datetime
test = pd.DataFrame([
    {'id': 1, 'date': datetime.fromisoformat('2016-01-01'), 'a': 1}, 
    {'id': 1, 'date': datetime.fromisoformat('2016-01-02'), 'a': 2}, 
    {'id': 1, 'date': datetime.fromisoformat('2016-01-03'), 'a': 3}]
)

lin_com_list = []
c = 0.
for a in test['a']:
    c = lin_comb(c or a, a, 0.9)
    lin_com_list.append(c)

test['lin_comb'] = lin_com_list
```

My question: is there an built-in function in Pandas that can generate the same output as above?

The reason I am asking is mainly performance. When you execute this function on millions of records this code is quite slow.

Comment: can you explain more about how the calculation works: when I apply my answer below which uses `(1 * 0.9 + 2 * 0.1) * 0.9 + 3 * 0.1` it does not produce the same result as your function on a larger frame.

Comment: @Yo_Chris The function is recursive as the `v1` parameter of the `lin_comb` function is always the accumulation of the previous results. If you see the function above you will see that the variable `c` is the input as well as the output.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize that `c` was also defined outside the function as well...should have read closer. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @Yo_Chris no problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually pandas supports exponential weighted averages which is more or less what I was looking for.

For my specific problem I ended up using the Pandas `ewm` function with a mean. So in essence this is the line of code that helped me to calculate exponential moving averages over a specific number of days:

```
dt[esmean_col] = grouped_sales.transform(lambda x : x.ewm(alpha=1/win, adjust=False).mean())
```

The `win` variable is the number of days in a window, in my case `7`.

And the performance of this implementation is really quite ok, as I could process 44 million records in less than 30 seconds.

More info on the Pandas `ewm` function [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a build-in function in pandas for this kind of recursive operation. But I think it is a good case for [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/index.html). I'm new to it so maybe some better way to do it, but the idea is:

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def numba_comb(arr_in, beta=0.9): 
    arr_out = np.zeros_like(arr_in)
    c = 0.
    for i in range(arr_in.shape[0]):
        a = arr_in[i]
        c = beta*(c or a) + (1-beta)*a
        arr_out[i] = c
    return arr_out
```

Comparison

```
def lin_comb(v1, v2, beta=0.9): return beta*v1 + (1-beta)*v2

def list_comb (ser, beta=0.9):
    lin_com_list = []
    c = 0.
    for a in ser:
        c = lin_comb(c or a, a, beta)
        lin_com_list.append(c)
    return lin_com_list
```

then it gives:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(1, 10000)})

# list solution
%timeit list_comb (test['a'], 0.9)
#3.51 ms ± 148 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# numba
%timeit numba_comb(test['a'].to_numpy().astype(float), 0.9)
#63.8 µs ± 990 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

#same result
print ((np.array(list_comb (test['a'])) 
        == numba_comb(test['a'].to_numpy().astype(float), 0.9)).all())
#True
```